# Anything better than PHPDoc out there?

Tags: php, documentation, documentation-generation, phpdoc

Does anybody use anything else to document their `PHP` code than `PHPDoc?`
Are there any tools that read the same documentation syntax but give richer output?

Comment: Please precise 'richer output'. Otherwise it's difficult to give precise answer.

Comment: What problems are you having with 5.3? (Also, running the doc generator via the command line version of PHP (with a custom ini with a larger memory allocation if necessary) would probably resolve the memory issue.

Comment: From what I understand of the situation, phpDocumentor does not support namespaces.  The memory issue is one I'm sure they've tried, though I could double check.

Comment: @user256162 It works with PHP 5.3, but all classes go to default package. I expected it to treat namespaces like packages. Anyone managed to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I´ll go for doxygen too.

Here are several reasons :

- compatible with phpdoc tags and other popular ones  : it´s interoperable
- works with various programming languages : a better time investment
- there is alternative syntaxes : can choose the commenting style that suit you
- very efficient with advanced formating / tagging / metadata
- there is a GUI that is not linked to any IDE and an eclipse plugin as well

And still free,  multiplatform, and open source :-)

It´s easy to learn, but harder that phpdoc because a lot richer.

Answer (score 8):

You could try DocBlox; which is intended to be an alternative for phpDocumentor but with support for additional features of which full PHP 5.3 support is one. An additional benefit is that is it quite fast and uses relatively little memory.

You can read more on http://www.docblox-project.org or see a demo at http://demo.docblox-project.org/default

Answer (score 7):

Another option other than phpDocumentor is [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) documentation with [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101146/anything-better-than-phpdoc-out-there) support.

Comment: You know know if the memory footprint of Doxygen is smaller than that of phpDocumentor?  Thanks!

Comment: To answer my own question, Doxygen is able to be pointed at much larger portions of our codebase than phpDocumentor.

Answer (score 5):

Doxygen ([www.doxygen.org](http://www.doxygen.org)).

Answer (score 3):

I've not used it with PHP, but [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) claims to support the language.

Answer (score 3):

### ApiGen

http://apigen.org/

ApiGen has support for PHP 5.3 namespaces, packages, linking between documentation, cross referencing to PHP standard classes and general documentation, creation of highlighted source code and experimental support for PHP 5.4 traits.

### DocBlox

http://www.docblox-project.org/

PHP 5.3 compatible API Documentation generator aimed at projects of all sizes and Continuous Integration.

able to fully parse and transform Zend Framework 2

Comment: http://apigen.org is lovley and I've been using that now.  It supports namespaces and has a lovely code output too.  Here's my ant config for it: `<target name="apigen"
            description="API documentation using apigen -- http://apigen.org/">
        <exec executable="apigen.bat">
            <arg value="--source" />
            <arg path="${basedir}/lib" />
            <arg value="--destination" />
            <arg path="${basedir}/build/docs" />
        </exec>`

Answer (score 2):

I am using [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org) too - you get used to the various keywords really fast - they are kind of self-explaining. ;)

[RubyDoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/)  is nice too, I espcially like they layout of the rdocs.

Answer (score 2):

Doctrine uses PHPDoctor, which appears to work well with 5.3 in my tests.

http://peej.github.com/phpdoctor/#download

Comment: +1 for PHPDoctor - it works amazingly well.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to document code for PHP 5.3+, eg. if it uses namespaces Ted Kulp's [fork of PHPDoctor](https://github.com/tedkulp/phpdoctor) might be your answer.