# PHP 5.3 Documentor?

Tags: php, documentation-generation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Anything better than PHPDoc out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101146/anything-better-than-phpdoc-out-there)

I was wondering if there is a documentation solution available that supports PHP 5.3.  We are having two problems with phpDocumentor.  First, it lacks 5.3 support. Second, it requires too much memory when used on our codebase.

Could anyone suggest viable alternatives to phpDocumentor?

Thank you!