# Is there any replacement for PHPDocumentor that supports PHP 5.3?

Tags: php, php-5.3, phpdoc

Some of the new PHP 5.3 features, including namespaces and anonymous functions, are not compatible with PHPDocumentor, even with the latest release. For example, it just raises an error when it encounters "a function with no name", i.e. a closure. So, are there any other open-source tools that generate API documentation (preferably in HTML) from Javadoc-style comments in PHP 5.3 code?

Comment: *Maybe* `Doxygen` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112654/php-5-3-documentor

Comment: Doxygen manages to finish creating the documentation, but the result is still nonsensical. It doesn't seem to parse the namespace declarations correctly, nor does it distinguish closure declarations from function calls.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, I've found [PHPDoctor](http://peej.github.com/phpdoctor/), which works pretty well with PHP 5.3. Although, I'd be still interested if anyone found something better, so I'm not closing the question.

Comment: My only regret is that I have but one vote to give!! I've been searching and searching for something that actually supported PHP5.3 and now I've found it!!

Comment: Being fed up with PHPDocumentor on PHP5.3, I had PHPDoctor installed, configured, and full documentation generated 10 minutes after learning it existed.  Nice.

Answer (score 14):

You could try DocBlox; which is intended to be an alternative for phpDocumentor but with support for additional features of which full PHP 5.3 support is one. An additional benefit is that is it quite fast and uses relatively little memory.

You can read more on http://www.docblox-project.org or see a demo at http://demo.docblox-project.org/default

Comment: Update: As of March 2012 has phpDocumentor and DocBlox merged into phpDocumentor2

Answer (score 6):

Check [ApiGen](http://apigen.org/) API documentation generator with PHP 5.3 support

Answer (score 1):

[YUI Doc](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/yuidoc/) is language agnostic. It could be used. Here's a video describing its use: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/video.php?v=woods-yuiconf2009-yuidoc

Answer (score 1):

This was already mentioned in a comment by @mvriel, but I'll make it an answer: phpDocumentor's successor is **[phpDocumentor 2](http://phpdoc.org/)**. From its website:

> phpDocumentor 2 is build to generate API documentation for all features available in PHP 5.3 and higher.

phpDocumentor 2 is the result of the merge between phpDocumentor and [DocBlox](http://www.docblox-project.org/). From the [merge announcement](http://www.docblox-project.org/2012/03/docblox-is-unmasked-it-is-really-phpdocumentor-2/) in DocBlox's website:

> Announcing phpDocumentor 2 – the merging of the old (phpDocumentor) and the new (DocBlox).
>
> ...
>
> Old phpDocumentor is retiring.  Some bugfix effort may continue into bringing phpDocumentor 1.x to a close, but most effort going forward will be spent on 2.x.

It's still in alpha stage (as of 2013-04-01), but usable.