# Is @package required with PHP 5.3 namespaces?

Tags: php, namespaces, php-5.3, phpdoc

I've switched to PHP 5.3 and the namespaces. It seems like the @package tag is redundant and useless now.

Is it still required by phpDoc, or can I ignore this tag now ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not required.

Latest doc now states that `@package` should be avoided if you use namespace and you don't need a different structure for documentation:

> If, across the board, both logical and functional subdivisions are
>   equal is it NOT RECOMMENDED to use the @package tag, to prevent
>   maintenance overhead.

http://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/package.html

Answer (score 1):

@package is not related to namespaces but to organizing the resulting documentation.

> Packages are used to help you
>   logically group related elements.
>   [phpDoc manual](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.package.pkg.html)

**EDIT**:

[Is there any replacement for PHPDocumentor that supports PHP 5.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2260936/562440)

Comment: How is "logically group related elements" different from namespaces ? I mean if that was up to me, I'd like my documentation grouped by namespaces now. What i'm wondering is : does the @package tag adds something more than namespaces ? (well except that for now it's the only way to organise the generated documentation)

Comment: @package simply has nothing todo with namespaces. namespace organize the code, @package organizes the doc. and they do that in completely independent and different ways. See edit for link.